# Prove that for all elements $a$ of a group, $a^k a^l = a^{k+l}$ for all $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, induction, cyclic-groups

This is my proof, using multiple induction.

Base Case: $k = l = 1$

$$(a^1)^1 := a^1 := a$$

Assume the inductive hypothesis $a^k a^l = a^{k+l}$

For $k+1$

$$(a^{k+1})^l = (a^k a)^l = (a^k)^l a^l = a^{kl} a^l = a^{kl+l} = a^{(k+1)l}$$

Similarly for $l+1$

$$(a^k)^{l+1} = (a^k)^l (a^k)^1 = (a^{kl}) a^k = a^{kl+k} = a^{k(l+1)}$$

I have already proved addition of powers before this exercise so that is assumed. My only problem is, can I assume $(ab)^l = a^l b^l$ for $a,b$ elements of a group and $l \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Thank you!

Comment: looks good to me, but I would do induction on $k+l$ to make this shorter

Comment: No, you cannot assume $(ab)^l = a^l b^l$. This isn't true unless $a$ and $b$ commute.

Comment: "I  have already proved addition of powers before this exercise"... Um, then *what* are you trying to prove here?  Your title says that the is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @fleablood From the base case, it looks like the asker is trying to prove $(a^{k})^{l}=a^{kl}$.

Answer (score 1):

I will use this definition: for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $x^{n}=x\cdots x$ ($n$ terms), $x^{0}=1$, $x^{-n}=x^{-1}\cdots x^{-1}$ ($n$ terms). I will use this property: $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$ for $a,b\in G$. We need a lemma first.

> **Lemma.** Let $x\in G$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Then $(x^{a})^{-1}=x^{-a}$.

*Proof of lemma.* We have
$$
\begin{split}
x^{a}x^{-a}&=(x\cdots x)(x^{-1}\cdots x^{-1}) \quad \textrm{($a$ terms each)}\\
&=1.
\end{split}
$$
Similarly, $x^{-a}x^{a}=1$. So $(x^{a})^{-1}=x^{-a}$.

*Proof of the question.*

Case 1: $k,l>0$.

Then
$$
\begin{split}
a^{k}a^{l}&=(a\cdots a)(a\cdots a) \quad \textrm{($k,l$ terms, respectively)}\\
&=a\cdots a \quad \textrm{($k+l$ terms)}\\
&=a^{k+l}.
\end{split}
$$

Case 2: $k$ or $l=0$. Easy.

Case 3: $k<0$ and $l>0$.

If $-k> l$, then 
$$
\begin{split}
a^{k}a^{l}&=a^{-(-k)}a^{l}=(a^{-k})^{-1}a^{l} \quad \textrm{by the lemma}\\
&=(a^{l}a^{-k-l})^{-1}a^{l} \quad \textrm{by case 1}\\
&=(a^{-k-l})^{-1}(a^{l})^{-1}a^{l}=a^{-(-k-l)} \quad \textrm{by the lemma}\\
&=a^{k+l}.
\end{split}
$$
If $-k\leq l$, then 
$$
\begin{split}
a^{k}a^{l}&=a^{-(-k)}a^{l}=(a^{-k})^{-1}a^{l} \quad \textrm{by the lemma}\\
&=(a^{-k})^{-1}a^{-k}a^{l-(-k)} \quad \textrm{by case 1 or case 2}\\
&=a^{k+l}.
\end{split}
$$

Case 4: $k>0$ and $l<0$. Similar to case 3.

Case 5: $k,l<0$.

Then 
$$
\begin{split}
a^{k}a^{l}&=a^{-(-k)}a^{-(-l)}=(a^{-k})^{-1}(a^{-l})^{-1} \quad \textrm{by the lemma}\\
&=(a^{-l}a^{-k})^{-1}=(a^{-l-k})^{-1} \quad \textrm{by case 1}\\
&=a^{-(-l-k)} \quad \textrm{by the lemma}\\
&=a^{k+l}.
\end{split}
$$